# NavigationView usage in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Coming from Android and working on a very complex application , i would like to use NavigationView as much as possible. Having one view and make all elements appear and disappear on this view seems impossible to handle for me .
I was using navigationView to navigate bewteen views with navigationBar hidden .
This way navigating or making view appear is transparent for the user

After some tests , i encounter limitations : at the 13th or 14 th level of navigation everything disappear and app basically crashes .

Once more , this is a direct navigation between 2 content views , no HOMESCREEN

```
import SwiftUI

struct test4: View {
    
    @State private var intent3: Bool =  false

    var body: some View {
      
        NavigationView{
  
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination : test3() , isActive : $intent3) { }
                Text("ver 4")
            .onTapGesture {
            intent3 = true }
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    
}
```

```
import SwiftUI


struct test3: View {
    
    @State private var intent4: Bool =  false

    var body: some View {
      
        NavigationView{
  
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination : test4() , isActive : $intent4) { }
                Text("ver 3")
            .onTapGesture {
            intent4 = true }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)    }
}
```

Here a basic example of navigation directly between 2 contents views . Crashes after 14/15 clicks. I encounter the same issue with  about any navigation link.

Comment: Thank you jpnpdx for helping me with the issue . For non swift specialists like me, i would like to add that the solution brought doesn t provide "equality' in the navigation . There will always be a "root view" (even if it is unnoticeable for the user),unlike to android .The path to the root view will be kept even if unshown . The other elements brought by jnpdx allow a "direct line" to the rootview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:
With your added code, I can see the initial crash was a result of adding a new `NavigationView` each time. This solves it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Test3()
        }
    }
}

struct Test4: View {
    @State private var intent3: Bool =  false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination : Test3() , isActive : $intent3) { }
            Text("ver 4")
                .onTapGesture {
                    intent3 = true
                }
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct Test3: View {
    @State private var intent4: Bool =  false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination : Test4() , isActive : $intent4) { }
            Text("ver 3")
                .onTapGesture {
                    intent4 = true }
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer**:

However, there are solutions to pop to the top of a navigation hierarchy.

One way is to use `isActive` to manage whether or not a given `NavigationLink` is presenting its view. That might look like this:

```
class NavigationReset : ObservableObject {
    @Published var rootIsActive = false
    
    func popToTop() {
        rootIsActive = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var navReset = NavigationReset()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "First"), isActive: $navReset.rootIsActive) {
                Text("Root nav")
            }
        }.environmentObject(navReset)
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var title : String
    @EnvironmentObject private var navReset : NavigationReset
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "\(Date())")) {
                Text("Navigate (\(title))")
            }
            Button("Reset nav") {
                navReset.popToTop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another trick you could use is changing an `id` on a `NavigationLink` -- as soon as that happens, it re-renders and becomes inactive.

```
class NavigationReset : ObservableObject {
    @Published var id = UUID()
    
    func popToTop() {
        id = UUID()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var navReset = NavigationReset()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "First")) {
                Text("Root nav")
            }
            .id(navReset.id)
        }.environmentObject(navReset)
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var title : String
    @EnvironmentObject private var navReset : NavigationReset
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(title: "\(Date())")) {
                Text("Navigate (\(title))")
            }
            Button("Reset nav") {
                navReset.popToTop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works by marking the first `NavigationLink` (ie the one on the Home Screen) with an `id`. As soon as that `id` is changed, the `NavigationLink` is recreated, popping all of the views off of the stack.

Comment: First , i thank you a lot for your time you spent . it will be difficult for me to apprenhend all this . Concerning th"crash by itself" : NavigationView {

Comment: Looks like something might be missing from the end of your comment. Let me know if you need more clarification on some element of my answer.

Comment: Lots of stuff in there that won't compile without extra code. Instead of adding this as a comment, try adding all of the relevant code as an edit to your question. But, probably only necessary if my solution doesn't work for you for some reason.

Comment: Sorry this is the code, clicking 13/14 times should produce the crash. I assumed this is normal behaviour because  it appends exactly at 14 clicks in other navigation views . Make it crash would make sense if the navigation bar wasnt hidden . If navigation isn t supposed to be limited (no mother view) , why  would it be needed to implement some extra code ?Thanx once more for all your time

Comment: Your edited example crashes because you embed a new `NavigationView` each time. Put it only on the parent element and it works fine.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the necessary change to your initial code.